# How to get data from Firebase with user_id which will match with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my Firebase real-time database console. I want to retrieve all data which is matched with inbox id

1.like 13 is my inbox id

2.I want to retrieve the list of data matched with id

[image]

Comment: Hello, if the answer was helpful you can accept it by clicking the tick icon and upvote by the up arrow icon so others will know it's resolved :D [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where the `user_id` is coming from but if you know it then you can just run this query:

```
const user_id = "the_id"

firebase.database().ref(`Inbox/${user_id}`).once("value").then((snapshot) => {
  console.log(snapshot.val())
})
```

The snapshot is a [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.DataSnapshot). You can read more about it in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data)

Comment: firebase.database().ref(`inbox/${prospectId}`).once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot.key);
        console.log(snapshot.val())

    });


I am getting key but not getting value it showing null on console

Comment: @RishikeshSingh Try `snapshot.val()` to get the data. `snapshot.key` gets the key of that node.

Comment: see again I am trying both but only getting key not data

Comment: @RishikeshSingh make sure you are saving the file and try restarting your web server.

Comment: yes I am doing same but not getting value

Comment: @RishikeshSingh can you please  share a screenshot?

Comment: @Dharmraj added in question please check

Comment: @RishikeshSingh I meant the output. Also how are you serving the webpage? If using firebase emulators, please try restarting.

Comment: it is a single PHP file page only

Comment: @RishikeshSingh but how are you serving it? Can you please share a screenshot of the output from your console?

Comment: added screenshot of browser please check

Comment: @RishikeshSingh it says null that means the data does not exists. I just noticed the I in your inbox is small in code but capital in database. Path is case sensitive please make it "Inbox" in the .ref()

Comment: @Dharmraj thanks so much I am missing this point now it's working fine thanks